# AJAX: How to get the last URL in a redirect flow inside an error handler with JSONP as content-type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, jsonp

I have a website with the following JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
var req = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://foo.com',

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // what is the last URL in the redirect flow?
    }
});
```

This is what happens:

Step 1) 
`http://foo.com` is requested, which returns a 302, and redirects to `http://bar.com`

Step 2)
`http://bar.com` is requested, **which does not contain valid JSONP** content (it's a HTML file), so the `req.error()` triggers, which is fine.

**What am I trying to achieve** is get the URL from step 2 (`http://bar.com`). This URL is **dynamic** (changes after every request). Also note I cannot do this request server-side (it's easy to do it, but it must be the client initiating that website from step 2).

I can see the redirect happening inside the Network tab in Chrome dev tools (as you can see, it's actually a three step flow but for the sake of simplicity, imagine it's a two step flow as I described above):
[image]

Note - I am using JSONP because of the fact that the remote server does not allow CORS.

Comment: hmm...I don't have time to verify this at the moment but what do you see if you look at `jqXHR. getResponseHeader('Location')` in your error handler?

Comment: @mherzig I get `null`.

Comment: Darn. Makes sense, I believe you would have to set the server to allow the header to be read.

Comment: Since this is a JSONP request, you're limited to what information you can obtain from the request since it is sent using a script tag rather than xhr.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use service worker to detect this since you are using jsonp.
But with that also means yours and the other site needs to run with https...

**Original answer**

I don't think xhr can do this but i guess the new fetch api can (if I'm not mistaken) using mode no-core won't work. the final url needs to have cors enabled...

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org//redirect/1').then(res => console.log(res.url))
```

Comment: I don't really care about JSONP or whatever, all I need is to know the last URL of the redirection flow.

Comment: I slightly changed your code because it was complaining about CORS: `fetch('http://example.com', {'mode': 'no-cors'}).then(res => console.log(res.url))`. This fixed CORS problem, and again I see the flow happening in Network tab in Chrome dev tools, but I don't see the redir flow showing on the console. (btw I didn't downvote your answer)

Comment: What do you mean, my site needs to run with HTTPS? I tried running this code on both a HTTPS site and against a HTTPS site - nothing change.

Comment: The only thing that can detect network redirect in src tags are service workers, and service workers are only allowed to run on https domain

Comment: Endless, are you saying I can accomplish my goal by using service workers? If so, can you suggest a google query on how to accomplish that?

Comment: [mdn service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)

Comment: Yep, I found that as well. Anyways, thank you - if it's possible, I'll do it.